# Will it be fine if i power the rear windows motor by tapping into 12v of cigarette lighter socket?

Tags: power-windows

my vehicle has all the power windows control switches together in one place at the centre console. It is very inconvenient for rear passengers to request driver to up/down their window glasses everytime. I decided to get universal power window 5 pin switch and install them at the rear doors. My confusion is that, do i necessarily have to tap the power from the original power window control box, or i'll just power the rear motors from a suitable 12v source like the 12v socket?

Comment: Are you suggesting that you will no longer be able to control them from the front of the vehicle?

Comment: actually im just trying to create a parallel switch for rear passengers like in most modern cars where there is driver-operated switches as well as rear controlled switches

Answer (score 1):

The cigarette lighter may not be capable of providing adequate current to power the rear window motor.  You'll want to verify the power requirements of the motor by checking its supply fuse and ensure that your lighter circuit can provide that amount of current.

If not then you may need to tap into power somewhere else.

Comment: There needs to be enough power to drive *all* the window motors at the same time, *and* when they reach the limit of travel and cause additional strain.

Comment: My "cigarette lighter" circuit is on a 20A fuse by itself. Check the one in your vehicle.

Comment: This is my first experience with an used vehicle and im willing to try the electric parts without having to take it to shop. I literally have zero experience with car wiring. I wonder is there a strong circuit in a car where you would tap most of aftermarket accessories and it would handle it without a problem..? (although i've recently learned about creating new circuit with relay and fuses)

Comment: Be careful about duplicating an existing circuit. I advise to *disconnect* the previous controls completely.

Answer (score 0):

Running it off of the cigarette lighter circuit may or may not work, depending on the draw of the window circuit in question.

I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to run it off of the power which is already provided through your current switch. You'd just need to run the new switches in parallel with the old switch. By doing so, you know that the power needs are already in place while not burdening any other circuit(s).

Comment: You're right. I think that shoyld be the way to go. Thing is, i would have to remove the centre console to access the line and this vehicle manufacturer over tightened every parts with too many screws and bolts. Guess i'd have to work my way into it anyhow.